# How to set a mamba environment R as the Windows default

Tags: r, windows, environment-variables, rstudio, mamba

When you install Rstudio Desktop on Windows you do not have the option to point it to a specific R. It will only look for the system R. If that doesn't exist, RStudio won't launch.

In the past I was using the miniconda installer on Windows. I always selected to add it to my windows path and installed everything in the base environment. This system worked.

I have decided to switch to the mambaforge installer. I also have decided to follow the advice of keeping a clean base environment. I created an environment called "default." I would like that to activate automatically when I open a cmd terminal, which I asked about in a previous issue.

I also need to have the R in that environment be my system default. This is all very easy in Linux. How do I accomplish this in Windows so I can install and launch RStudio Desktop?